# Is there a way to programmatically check if a Flink streaming job started from a savepoint before executing the stream?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Before calling `execute` on the `StreamExecutionEnvironment` and starting the stream job, is there a way to programmatically find out whether or not the job was restored from a savepoint? I need to know such information so that I can set the offset of a Kafka source depending on it while building the job graph.

It seems that the `FlinkConnectorKafkaBase` class which has a method `initializeState` has access to such information ([code](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/68cc21e4af71505efa142110e35a1f8b1c25fe6e/flink-connectors/flink-connector-kafka-base/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/kafka/FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.java#L864)). However, there is no way to intercept the `FunctionInitializationContext` and retrieve the `isRestored()` value since `initializeState` is a `final` method. Also, the `initializeState` method gets called after the job graph is executed and so I don't think there is a feasible solution associated to it.

Another attempt I made was to find a Flink job parameter that indicates whether or not the job was started from a savepoint. However, I don't think such parameter exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the effect you are looking for by simply doing this:

```
FlinkKafkaConsumer<String> myConsumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>(...);
myConsumer.setStartFromEarliest();
```

If you use setStartFromEarliest then Flink will ignore the offsets stored in Kafka, and instead begin reading from the earliest record. Moreover, even if you use setStartFromEarliest, if Flink is resuming from a checkpoint or savepoint, it will instead use the offsets stored in that snapshot.

Note that Flink does its own Kafka offset management, and when recovering from a checkpoint ignores the offsets stored in Kafka. Flink does this as a part of providing exactly-once guarantees, which requires knowing exactly how much of the input was consumed to produce the results present in the rest of the state captured in a checkpoint or savepoint. For this reason, Flink always stores the offsets as part of every state snapshot (checkpoint or savepoint).

This is documented [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/kafka.html#kafka-consumers-start-position-configuration) and [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/kafka.html#kafka-consumers-and-fault-tolerance).

As for your original question about `initializeState`, this is available if you implement the `CheckpointedFunction` interface, but it's quite rare to actually need this.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer... The problem is that `initializeState` is called after the job topology is constructed and the job is executed. I need to know this information while the job graph is being built, before `execute` is called to start the job, since after the job is executed there isn't a way to change the configuration of the job's operators.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Normally it is enough that the savepoint contains the Kafka offsets, along with the corresponding state throughout the rest of the jobgraph.

Comment: A Flink job reading from Kafka, I'm trying to make the job reset its offset to read from the beginning if a checkpoint isn't passed in, if it is passed in make the job continue with the Kafka group offset. Also, afaik Kafka offsets aren't stored in the checkpoint, they are stored and tracked by Kafka.

Comment: Thank you for the help.